# How/where to set Yii2 Login Controller/Method

Tags: yii2

How/where do you set the controller/method Yii2 uses when a user is required to be logged in? Currently it goes to site/login and I'm trying to point it to auth/login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using advanced template in your config/main.php (or main-local.php) you should define your user component  g for frontented app

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\web\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'loginUrl'=>['/frontend/auth/login'],
],
```